Given a n-cube, why is it that in a net we can't have cycles in its facet-graph?
Let's take it easier to visualize first, given a normal 3 dimensional cube in real life an cut along its edges (ridges more formally called) we can unfold it into the $xy$ plane if the cube was sitting on top of it. One way think to think of this is to think of the faces of the cube as a nodes and the connective edges between faces as edges in this new abstract graph. An unfolding is a subgraph such that it mustn't have any isolated nodes, otherwise there would be a totally cutoff face of the cube (that is to say that the graph is connected) and that there are no cycles of any size in it. So that means that an unfolding is a spanning tree of the graph of the cube.
In the general case, given an n-dimensional cube, construct the graph that represents its facets and the edges are its ridges, then an unfolding is a spanning tree of this graph.
My question: is this "no-cycle" rule necessary in higher dimension? Sure in 3 dimensional and even 2 dimensional cubes it makes sense that we need this but why would higher dimensional analogues need this condition too? Just because a rule seems beautifully nice to generalize doesn't mean that we should extrapolate with it. Couldn't it be possible to unfold, let's say, a 4-cube such that it contains cycles? Or a 10-cube having a 7-cycle in it can still be unfolded somehow into a lower dimension?

It is a bit hard to follow what you mean. But if you want to "unfold" a $n$-cube, meaning cutting it and then embedding it in dimension $n-1$, you cannot have cycles as a cycle cannot be embedded in lower dimension.

Thanks for taking your time @MathieuRundström, but this is exactly my questions, why can't cycles be embedded in lower dimensions?

I feel like this is somehow related to rigidity theory. The graph you get from thinking of faces of the hypercube as vertices etc. is the 1-skeleton of the cross-polytope. Maybe this will give you some ideas.

I think that cycles may very well be possible for non-convex shapes, maybe even in 3 dimensions.
For the hypercube in particular, there is the following argument.
Walking around the unfolded $(n-1)$-dimensional net of the hypercube, no matter which facet you're on, you can ask: "If I were to go north/south/easy/any of the $2n-2$ available directions, which facet of the $n$-cube would I end up on?" The important thing to observe is this:
For a particular $(n-1)$-dimensional direction $d$, the facet in direction $d$ from you does not change if you move to a different facet in a direction orthogonal to $d$.
This puts us in a bind when trying to find a cycle in a net. Suppose that your goal is to walk around in the net and come back to where you started, but without revisiting the same facet twice. Let $d$ be some direction that you end up walking in at some point. Overall, to return to where you started, you must walk in direction $d$ and $-d$ an equal number of times. So consider a segment of your walk where you step in direction $d$, walk around in directions orthogonal to $\pm d$ for a while, and then step back in direction $-d$.
The problem is that, if $F$ is the facet which you were on before you stepped in direction $d$, then $F$ is the facet in direction $-d$ afterwards. This remains true for as long as you step in directions orthogonal to $\pm d$. So when you step back in direction $-d$, you end up at a different location in $(n-1)$-dimensional space... corresponding to the same facet $F$!
But then our net is not a net: it contains multiple $(n-1)$-cubes corresponding to the same facet of the $n$-cube. (If we're allowed to do that, it's easy to find "nets" even of the $3$-dimensional cube that contain cycles.) So if we have an actual net which contains only $2n$ $(n-1)$-cubes, one for each facet of the $n$-cube, then it cannot contain a cycle.
